# Does it Make Sense to have ViewModels in the Webapi?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am starting to learn the webapi and find myself doing stuff that makes sense in an MVC project but may not make sense in.

Normally in an MVC project I make ViewModels and use that as the parameter or pass them back with the view.

Since there are no views in webapi I guess it does not make sense to have a ViewModel as parameter.

I am wondering maybe if I should just have as a Parameter my EF domains(code first) and put data annotations on top of these. I normally would put the annotations over the view model properties as I liked this over the domain.

However what is stopping me from doing this is I am not 100% clear how my MVC site would work.

Does the MVC site just spit back simples views and then you use Jquery to call your webapi or do you just call MVC action methods that directly just call the same methods the Webapi would call?

If is the second way then I rather put the data annotations on my view model again but then I am putting the same ones on both the EF domain and VM's and that seem redundant.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Terminology aside, having models for binding to is still of use. They just aren't technically ViewModels anymore, in that you're right there are no views involved. But they are definitely still of use. Using them allows you to take advantage of attributes on your Model's properties and allows you to reuse them across your API if needed. Also remember if you use your entities directly WebAPI will model bind all parameters to them that match by name, even if you didn't mean to.

Also, the Entity Models are representations of your raw data, but the Models used for binding against are a fixed contract that the API requests need to satisfy to successfully process a request. The values in which, could end up spanning multiple entity models by the time your implementation is done, and not be persisted to a data store at all.

Comment: Ya that is one of the reasons why I don't like putting my annotations on the EF itself. I guess I should use a viewModel but just call it something else DataModel? I am still not clear on how the whole website will work. For instance I will have an Add method. Mobile device and website both can add. Should the MVC site call the webapi method as well? In this case it seems to make sense. But how about an Edit Case in mobile again seems to make sense to call the webapi but on the site it seems like you would rather use mvc to get a view back that is binded and then post back to that view.

Comment: I ran across the same problem and the decision I came to is that it didn't makes sense to have some of my site use MVC for sending/retrieving data and use WebApi for others (sent from the MVC site). The main benefit of the WebApi is to allow outside assets use your data/business rules directly via an API. If you're already have an MVC site in the same project, why force it to go through WebApi to interact with your domain if you can use MVC directly? And I agree a slightly different name change would make it clearer. InputModel? RequestModel? It's just terminology, and is really the same thing

Comment: I guess you create a separate project for your mvc site then and have it in the same solution as the webapi. I know the webapi can have mvc controllers but I am thinking that is more for like displaying documentation and such about you api to the user.

Comment: I disagree that there is no 'View'. I would refer to the JSON or XML returned as a view, usually for another non-human consumer.

Comment: In a fashion I suppose one could argue that. Though to me a view is the representation of the data in a human readable form. Where as JSON or XML is just the raw data serialized to a text only format. It's just the data formatted as text before sending it over the wire since the HTTP protocol is primarily text. In a way I could one could argue a View is any unstructured representation of the data. Thus leaving the Model as the structured representation.

Comment: >>> Also, the Entity Models are representations of your raw data, but the Models used for binding against are a fixed contract that the API requests need to satisfy << IMO this is the strongest argument

Comment: So if they aren't called ViewModels - what should we call them? Is there conventional terminology?

Comment: I don't think I've ever encountered a specific convention for them, you can call them whatever you like, but I'd try and pick something indicative of what their intended use it. I've tossed around the idea of InputModel and RequestModel above. Maybe ApiModel, or even ParametersModel (since the original question was specifically about using these models for binding rules via data annotations as parameters for the actions). If you want, you could use an even more generic naming convention of Model, and just put them in a grouped namespace. Up to you :-)

Answer (score 46):

My suggestion after loooong time working with this *'things'* :

**BindingModels** for data binding (mvc or api)

**ViewModels** for views on mvc (you may have some mvc pages inside your api, so it's good to have a 
place for this, this can be documentation, intro page, whatever. If there is none view, then you can have zero ViewModels) One benefit of this is that you can in your Views/web.config have the ViewModels namespace reference and it won't be polluted with your api resources.

**ResourceModel** for web api resources. In webapi, nested resources are also resources that go anywhere in a tree which is not that common on mvc, so naming them resources make a lot of sense.

If you want to receive a resource, you can use your resource model. Remember your are receiving the same  your are sending back.

If you want a custom binding for input (this should be your default scenario) you have your binding models.

If you have any mvc view, for admin purposes, documentation, whatever, use your ViewModels.

If you have a form page on mvc, you can use your BindingModel also on the POST controller. No need to have a different model for a post on MVC or WEBAPI. Specially when model binder or formatter can both understand and map to the same binding model using the same Data Annotations.

Sometimes, you want to create a binding model with a resource and some extra fields. Inheritance is your friend.

Sometimes you want to create binding model with more than one resource and (optionally, extra fields) Resources as properties are your friend.

In MVC world, you can also use the concept of 'Resource' but it is much less common. This come in handy when you have MVC and Web Api on the same project.

If you need further comments on any item (like folder structure, namespaces, etc), just let me know. I'm more than happy to share my cons pros experience.

Oh, and I forgot, a mapping strategy is worth research. I personally do my own mappings, but having this *logic* in one place is priceless.

EDIT: 
Very naive example

```
ContactViewModel{

    string Name {get;}
    string LastName {get;}
    List<Country> AvailableCountries {get;}
    Country Country {get;}
    bool IsAdmin {get;}

}

ContactBindingModel{

    string Name {get;set;}
    string LastName {get;set;}
    int Country {get;set;}

}

ContactResourceModel{

    string Name { get;set;}
    string LastName {get;set;}
    Country Country {get;set;}
    string IsAdmin {get;}

}
```

Comment: I like your approach on this. What type of naming conventions and structure are you using for your class files? It's quite common to name a classic View Model in MVC for "MyModelNameViewModel". Are you using the same principals for but for BindingModels and ResourceModels as well? And/or do you use separate folders for the different model types?

Comment: I do something similar. I have ViewModels for passing back to views, and bind my requests against FormModels, since most times I'm binding against a form from a webpage (MVC), though I could see calling them BindingModels as well for things like WebAPI and have them be more universally named. My naming convention is typically something like `[Controller][Action]ViewModel`. So I might end up with something like `PeopleEditFormModel`

Comment: @jimutt Lately I was investing and researching a lot in a feature folder structure instead of controllers/models/views. etc. Before I was using `[Model]Resource` for resources, `[Controller][Action]ViewModel` for viewmodels and `[Command]BindingModel` for binding models, (where command is the intended action, like CancelOrder, CreateModel, etc) Usually the Command = ActionName.

Comment: What is the difference between the ResourceModel and the BindingModel? If it isn't much to ask, can you give an example? :p

Comment: BindingModel is what you post from a <form post> (that you bind to an object) while a ResourceModel (or ApiModel if you wish) it's the data representation of a particular model of api enpoint(s).

Comment: @BartCalixto really nice approach. May I ask for the project folder naming and structure for this? or if you have written an article about it, what's the Url? Thank you.

Comment: I've been thinking about this approach and especially 'BindingModels' for a while. I thought it's not good, but once I saw your post, it made me veryyyy happpy :)

Comment: I know it's been many years since this has been posted, but it has helped me immensely. Such a great post to help understand you don't have to lump everything into a single model type.

Comment: I read this answer earlier and I've been thinking about it all day. Up until now I've always just had a ViewModel with all of the properties I'll ever need for binding, viewing, etc. Seems silly now I think about it. I was just playing around with your idea, though, and so I have a base EventModel which I inherit in an EventViewModel, an EventBindingModel and an EventResourceModel. Problem is that some properties are common to EventViewModel and EventResourceModel but not EventBindingModel so I don't want to put them in the base model but also don't want to repeat them in the derived models.

Comment: Repeat is fine, because is not really replication. Your binding model requires validation rules and many times you'll need nullable inputs when your models don't.

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to build a REST based system then the notion of ViewModel and View can be very useful.  You can fairly closely map the notion of Resource to ViewModel and representation to View.

If you stop to think for a moment about what a view looks like in an MVC site.  It's a HTML document.  A document that contains a bunch of semantic information, title, body, sections, paragraphs, tables, etc.  It's not supposed to contain "style" information.  That's the job of the web browser and CSS.  People get confused when they start to think of HTML as UI. It's not supposed to be UI, it is the content of the UI.

Views are just a concrete realization of the view model content using some media type that can be transferred over the wire.  What that media type is, depends on what client you are trying to satisfy.

Answer (score 3):

We are currently working on a similar project that uses ASP.Net MVC and ASP.Net Web Api.

We use ASP.Net MVC to generate the global structure of our pages.
Then, our MVVM javascript implementation calls the web api to fill returned data in client view models.  To do that, our api returns view model that correspond to what the front end is waiting for.

I think that your api view models would differ from MVC ViewModels (that are not ViewModels from a MVVM point of view).

It depends on your use of api too. For example, for an internal use, you don't always need to avoid to show your domain model. So you will avoid to map the Model in the ViewModel and increase performances.
But in the case you need to transform some properties in your models, viewModels will greatly help you to structure your code in a loosely coupled way.

> Since there are no views in webapi I guess it does not make sense to have a ViewModel as parameter.

I would say your api is consumed by your views in the end, it makes sense to have ViewModel.

> Does the MVC site just spit back simples views and then you use Jquery to call your webapi or do you just call MVC action methods that directly just call the same methods the Webapi would call?

It is just a question of choice here. You can call MVC action to receive generated views (in html) or you can call WebApi to receive JSON/XML responses that you will then bind with your javascript code in your views.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add what others have said, the use of what would normally be termed a ViewModel is useful for validation as well. You can mark up your classes with data annotations including any validation requirements. In your controller actions you can still use ModelState to force the validation to occur and return appropriate messages via HttpRequestException or just HttpResponseMessage.