# How to change business model properties accessibility in mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, asp.net-web-api2

So, i have this class

```
 public abstract class Entity<T> : IEntity<T>, IAuditableEntity,ISoftDeletable where T : struct
    {
        public T Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }
```

which, down the line allows me to create classes like

```
public class User : Entity<int>
    {    
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public byte LoginTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual LoginType LoginType { get; set; }
    }
```

Which will be manipulated by repositories like this one:

```
 public abstract class Repository<TEntity,TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : Entity<TKey> where TKey : struct

    {
        protected DbContext Context;
        protected readonly IDbSet<TEntity> Set;

        protected Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
            Set = Context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public TEntity Get(TKey key)
        {
            return Set.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id.Equals(key));
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {

            return Set.AsEnumerable();
        }
}
```

The objective is that this will be used in some WebApi2 controller, but as good rules dictate i should not expose the User class as it is (and im not allowed to).

My requirement is that the base properties (Id, Datetime, Deleted, etc) become readonly at the controller level, but obviously read/write at the repository level.

For instance, the controller cannot set the Deleted property directly, but it must be set by the repository when the Delete operation is called.

I could hide inherited properties but i cannot disallow anyone from doing

```
var u= new User();
var baseEntity = (Entity<int>) u;
```

So, how can i have the User entity WITH the base properties as readonly at the controller level?

Comment: Why not set the properties that the controller shouldn't  be able to access as protected, then add get methods for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use view models in your webapi project to only expose the data you want.  See this related question [Does it Make Sense to have ViewModels in the Webapi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365773/does-it-make-sense-to-have-viewmodels-in-the-webapi)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way, assuming you `Entity`, `Controller`, and `Repository` are in different projects, is to use the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

You would first change all the properties that should only be visible to the `Repository` Project to `internal` properties. You will then use the `InternalsVisibleTo` class so that they are visible to that project.

In this case however, they will still also be visible to the project where `Entity` is.